# Element created using document.createElement() then setting id is undefined using document.getElementById() later

Tags: javascript, html, dom, audio

Please see this https://jsfiddle.net/vpLbvp0o/17/ for an example of what my issue is.

I am trying to create audio elements dynamically, layering music on the html page. Here is what I am doing when creating a new audio element and playing the music:

```
const new_layer = document.createElement("audio");
new_layer.id = "hello";
new_layer.src = "some_sound.mp3";
new_layer.play();
```

This works and the music starts to play. Later, if I want to reference this same element using its id that I have set to pause the music or update the src, using `document.getElementById("hello")` returns null. The element cannot be found, but the music is still obviously playing in the DOM. How do I reference this element that I have obviously created and is still there? In the jsfiddle, you can see that I am waiting with a timeout before trying to retrieve the element, but it seems like it's just not there.

If I do the same thing with an element that was already defined in the HTML document, then everything works fine. Is this a limitation of dynamically creating elements using JavaScript?

Comment: You should probably use `element.id = "id";`

Comment: Also, `audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio"); ` should be `audio_list = document.getElementsByTagName("audio"); `;

Comment: You already have the Element with your `new_layer` variable. It would be pointless to get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The node isn't in the DOM, you need to add it.

`document.body.appendChild(new_layer);`

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` gets element with specified `id` **from `document`**, and you did not append it to the document

```js
const player = document.createElement("AUDIO");
player.setAttribute("id", "hello");
player.src = "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3";
player.play();
console.log(player.id);
console.log(player);

document.body.appendChild(player);

let get_player;
let audio_list;
setTimeout(function() {
 get_player = document.getElementById("hello");
 audio_list = document.getElementsByTagName("audio"); 

  console.log(get_player);
  console.log(audio_list);
}, 1000);

// Try pausing and playing the audio element. It does not work.
setTimeout(function() { get_player.pause(); }, 5000);
setTimeout(function() { get_player.play(); }, 10000);
```

```html
<audio id="ambient"></audio>
<audio id="background"></audio>
```